# Why do airplanes use AC electric power?

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system

Primary electric power on larger airplanes is provided as AC. What aspects of aircraft make AC a better choice than DC?

Comment: if you search for "dc ac spike" or "dc ac Voltage spike" you will see that this property alone, from the AC power, can be enough to justify the adoption of it against the DC.

Comment: @user2485710 I have no idea what you're talking about.  Care to share a link?  You can put voltage spikes on any power line, it doesn't matter if it's DC, AC, or 12-phase

Comment: @NickT yes, but AC reacts way better than DC. ask here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2485710 I have over 9000 rep on that site and am an electrical engineer.  I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @NickT in short handling a spike in a DC system it's more expensive and less reliable than what an AC system can do.I lost the links to the articles that were explaining this.For example in your house you probably have AC,your pc is probably connected to a power surge, to protect your PC from a spike in a **DC** world you would need to dissipate the current that is the "extra" voltage from the spike as heat, with AC you have a lot of cheaper and more reliable options http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector .People use lightning rod wired to the ground against lightnings not giant heaters.

Comment: Something interesting (to me at least) is that in the Dassault Falcon aircraft, they eliminated the AC bus in newer aircraft and generate 100% DC.  Where AC is needed for specific instruments, they replaced the instruments with versions that had built-in inverters.  So I wouldn't assume that all airplanes are using AC.  Perhaps (just a guess) larger airplanes are going to AC because of the longer wire runs?

Comment: @user2485710 those surge protectors are also dissipating the excess voltage as heat by using [MOVs or other non-linear devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector#Metal_oxide_varistor_.28MOV.29).  TVSs, for example, are used on DC power lines (and data lines) fairly frequently to suppress everything from ESD to heavy-truck alternator load dumps which can shove >100 VDC onto an automotive DC bus.

Comment: I haven't seen anyone here mention the interesting artifact of "DC dies and AC lies" -- that is, DC powered instruments tend to drop to zero when power fails, AC instruments (like the torque gauges on the King Air) freeze wherever they were last, which is NOT a very friendly failure mode. Incidentally the King Airs have all of: 28V DC, 28VC AC, and 110V AC.

Comment: Adding to @Lnafziger 's comment, I think the only advantages of using AC is the easiness of generation and of voltage conversion (and good quality of the converted-voltage current). Else transporting AC is not as efficient as DC (due to reactive power), and as a matter of fact is not used on very long lines (like inter-country [HVDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current) lines). Many electronic devices need DC (albeit at low voltage).

Comment: @mins HVDC lines are not used for distance reasons. They are used because it is very hard to synchronise two country's AC phase. True, you may find HVDC used for under water cables for distance reasons... But most planes spend very little time under water.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

AC is easier to produce with the engines, that act as generators. 
The engines have a rotating shaft that it is easily equipped with magnetic dipoles all around.

[image]

Then, depending on the instrument, the current is either used directly or, by the use of converters, in DC form as not only it is easier to produce, it is also easier to convert. So electronic devices that uses 12, 5 or 3V may contain their own voltage converter (though this is less and less true with modern efficient switch-mode converters). If DC conversion was as much efficient as AC conversion, we wouldn't see high-voltage lines. Last but not least, it's easier to switch, because the current is null twice per cycle. DC must be switched at full current, which is expensive and weight costly. (thanks mins)

Comment: Not entirely correct, I think. The AC needs typically be 400 Hz constant frequency, regardless of how fast the engine is spinning. So the engine and the generator are connected with a Constant Speed Drive unit, which in essence an automatic transmission that keeps the generator at constant speed.

Comment: @Hilmar I left that out on purpose, it is not required to understand "why AC instead of DC".

Comment: @Hilmar That's not always true-some aircraft have variable "wild" frequency power 350-800Hz depending on engine speed.

Comment: @Federico: Except it's kind of essential. There are no DC generators, only AC generators with converter. But when there is a converter, the frequency does not matter. When there is not, the frequency _and the phase_ must match, which is quite a bit of complication.

Comment: That's an inefficient diagram you have there, 2 south poles, 4 north poles on the rotor!

Comment: @JanHudec It is perfectly possible to produce DC without producing AC and rectifying it. The device called a [dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo); early electrical distribution systems used these and supplied direct current. This is where the whole "[War of the Currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_Currents)" came from.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, actually, yes, it is possible to produce DC without producing AC first, but not with a dynamo. In dynamo the commutator that rectifies it is directly on the shaft, but in the windings the current is still alternating. Batteries, fuel cells and homopolar generators do generate DC directly.

Comment: @JanHudec I think that claiming that a dynamo has AC internally is being unnecessarily pedantic. A dynamo is a device where the only way of connecting to it gives you DC. It may well have alternating currents internally but there's no way to connect to that. It's not meaningful to describe a dynamo as being an alternator connected to some kind of rectifier, since you can't separate out those two components.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, but it is exactly what I was meaning right from the start. Since dynamo is exactly the same as alternator except it uses commutator in the output, it would not make anything easier (well, it would; dynamos wouldn't have to be phase-synchronized).

Comment: @DavidRicherby, anyway, since dynamo and alternator are essentially the same except for the connection, this answer does not actually explain the choice at all.

Comment: I wish people would explain why they downvote.

Comment: It's easier to produce, and it's also easier to convert, so electronic devices that uses 12, 5 or 3V may contain their own voltage converter (though this is less and less true with modern efficient switch-mode converters). If DC conversion was as much efficient as AC conversion, we wouldn't see high-voltage lines. Last but not least, it's easier to switch, because the current is null twice per cycle. DC must be switched at full current, which is expensive and weight costly.

Comment: Downvoted because it is not how it is done. AC generators are very seldom connected directly to the engine distributing varying frequencys to the rest of the plane. The normal way is for the generator to produce DC (often enough by rectifying an AC generator). The DC is then converted into a stable 400Hz AC to feed some equipment. In a large plane you might find quite a few electrical buses, some 400Hz, some 60 or 50Hz, different DC voltages.

Comment: @ghellquist please have a look at the comments above. You'll see that other users say that there are no DC generators. who should I listen to?

Comment: @Federico: part of this confusion is language usage. English wikipedia has this description. I cannot say whether it is right or wrong: "Terminology: Electromagnetic generators fall into one of two broad categories, dynamos and alternators.

- Dynamos generate pulsing direct current through the use of a commutator
- Alternators generate alternating current". If we use this description, in the World War II most aeroplane generators where dynamos, creating a pulsating DC. In order to create AC there would be an inverter (motor + alternator).

Comment: @ghellquist then why did you downvote? I am not speaking of WW2 planes, but modern larger airplanes, as asked in the question

Answer (score 16):

What the other answers have failed to note is that on a plane, its not just AC power, but 3 phase AC power.

Depending on how the plane is wired up, you will either get the benefit of reduced cable weight or higher reliability (or some blend of the two).

**Delta**

If the plane is wired up with a Delta transformer, then 3 wires are used to carry the electricity. However, what is crazy is that the Delta transformer (or alternator) will continue to run (albeit at a lower capacity) with one of the windings destroyed.

**Wye**

In a balanced wye configuration the 4 wires come from the transformer. Each of the first three wires carry current from the transformer, with the 4th as the common "return". However since each of the wires are "balanced", the actual current on the common is approximately zero (and not the 3 * current of the output). That means your 3 "live" wires only needs to be thick enough to carry the current one way. (typically with DC you would need to have wire thickness to carry the current there then back again). So in effect we can achieve the same power transmission with half the weight of a DC setup.

Since on planes, both redundancy (safety) and weight (economy) are both massive factors in cost. It is actually economical to run power on AC, and convert to DC where necessary.

Answer (score 13):

The size, weight, and cost of switchgear for DC-DC conversion at any given power is much higher than AC-AC and AC-DC conversion. So whether a piece of equipment requires AC or DC, it can be converted more easily from an AC source than from a DC source - but more importantly, it can be done with less weight, volume, and cost.

It's the same reason 400Hz is used rather than 50Hz or 60Hz - weight.  A generator or transformer that can handle a given load is physically smaller and lighter at higher frequencies due to issues with core saturation at lower frequencies.  A smaller, lighter core can be used for higher frequencies.

While switchgear has evolved over the decades, and weight and cost aren't as big an issue as they were in the past, the generator itself still has to have a stator and windings, and these are still physically smaller and lighter for a given power output than the equivalent DC, or low frequency AC generator.

Comment: Since DC generator is just an AC generator with converter, it can be made from high-frequency one and thus have the same low weight. It is even advantageous, because less stabilization is needed.

Comment: @JanHudec *"DC generator is just an AC generator with converter"* I suppose you can make it this way, rather than using a real DC generator. But why?  An AC generator without an AC-DC converter is still lighter and cheaper than an AC generator with a converter.  Further, what are you going to do with that DC? You're going to have more expensive and heavier DC-DC and DC-AC converters throughout the plane. AC-DC and AC-AC converters are still cheaper and lighter.

Comment: @AdamDavis: You'll need some conversion electronics by the generators in both cases -- the rotation of the several engines that may provide power is not synchronized, so just feeding the raw output from each AC generator into a common bus wouldn't end well anyway. (And in contrast to terrestial power plants, producing electricity is not the main task of a plane's engines so you cannot just adjust the engine speeds to lock frequency between the generators).

Comment: There is no "real DC generator". Electromagnetic induction only works with _changing_ magnetic fields and thus produces _changing_ current. So a DC generator is either wound generator with commutator instead of two separate rings or an induction generator with diode converter. There is no reason why it couldn't run at the same rpm as the AC generator and consequently no reason to be heavier.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's true, particularly on modern and larger multi-engine planes. The reason we do it today is largely historical. Lots of planes now have DC and AC buses, multiple generators, buses, and converters that will power one or more buses from the others depending on circumstances. They could change the systems completely over to DC, but it would require a significant change in the industry to justify the cost. We are now building planes based on the decisions made years ago due to the weight difference of direct AC and DC generators

Comment: @JanHudec I understand what you're saying, however all of my reading suggests that isn't the case.  If you have additional technical references showing that DC generators are as light as AC for a given power output, please update http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility_frequency#400_Hz at least, and let the Us government know one of the basis of MIL-STD-704 is incorrect. The DC/AC question has more to do with historically easier/cheaper/lighter power conversion at individual points along the plane for specific historical reasons. But my research suggests AC generators were lighter as well.

Comment: @AdamDavis: That paragraph does not compare to DC, only to lower frequency AC. The point against DC is obviously that it can't be transformed.

Answer (score 7):

Does it have to be aircraft-specific reasons? I would imagine the reasons are not necessarily very aircraft related:

- Different subsystems need different working voltages internally, and supplying AC makes it easy for each component to transform down to whatever it needs.
- Where mechanical power is needed, asynchronous AC motors are a lot simpler (especially in terms of maintenance requirements) than DC motors.
- Engineering inertia. All kinds of components already come expecting AC; even if DC is *in isolation* superior for some uses (as it might well be for electronics, with today's solid-state voltage converters) supplying DC to aircraft systems would mean that you need to have a DC supply network *in addition* to the AC supply for those components that are not yet available and certified in DC versions. That extra wiring alone might easily offset the advantages of having some of power supplies be lighter.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that aeroplanes use both AC and DC for powering the various subsystems:

If energy has to be stored in accumulators - well, they only store DC current. But
if generators are involved you won't have a chance of totally avoiding AC since a rotating movement is essentially sinusoidal:

- If you put a rotating magnet into a coil it will produce an alternating magnetic field in the coil => the coil will produce AC
- and if you put a rotating coil into a magnetic field the field will alternate between going through the coil in one direction and in the other again producing AC current.

One can now put the AC through a rectifier or use a wiper (a switch that can reverse the current and is mechanically triggered twice at every revolution of the generator). But if you rectify a sinus you still get a voltage that goes up and down, only it no more passes the zero level. This means you will sometimes draw too much energy from the generator (when the voltage is high) and at every revolution the voltage will shortly drop to zero meaning you won't be able to draw any energy at all.

If you don't constantly draw energy from a generator, the generator will vibrate.
You wouldn't like that in an aeroplane but there is a remedy:

Using three-phase AC: You can generate three sine waves with the same generator using coils that are a third of a revolution apart. When the voltage from one of these coils drops, the voltage at the two other coils rises - and the power produced (which is linear to the voltages squared) will add up to a constant flow.

The next thing one has to know that if you want a constant stream of power from a motor the same reasons make you use three AC waves here, too.

Normally this AC is generated from a DC voltage, though, because you might want to adjust the frequency the motor is running at or the amount of power it provides hence you want to adjust the frequency of the voltage the motor gets.

Answer (score 2):

This goes back to the 1930-s and has been kept because it was a good solution and still works.

In the 1930-s the big electronic revolution started and accelerated in the second world war. This is of course before the transistor, so vacuum tubes where used in radios, radars and so on. The generators on the engines were DC-generators and feeding batteries (remember, no diodes available for AC generators). But the vacuum tube elecronics boxen needed several different voltages inside: something like 6.3V for heating and several other voltages, say 12V and 400V. In order to produce these transformers were the best solution. But transformers need to be fed AC.

To create AC an inverter were used. In those days, a DC motor connected to an AC generator. The RPM of the DC generator was, somewhat, regulated to get in the ballpark correct AC frequency.

As the weight of a transformer is, somewhat again, inversely proportional to the frequency you would want a high frequency in order to keep weight down. As losses increase, again somewhat, proportional to frequency, you would want to have a low frequency. Somewhat in the middle of frequencies the engineers, who incidentally knew exactly what the were doing, landed on 400Hz as a reaonable compromise.

And now we keep on using 400Hz, simply because it works. All of the components and lots of the engineering decisions has changed, but 400Hz AC still is a good in the middle compromise.

You might be interested to check this manual: [b24 electrical system](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hu1F9PTWG28C&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=b-24%20liberator%20electrical%20system&source=bl&ots=gAlPD4R5LF&sig=7iVbrv5fIxAnoXX3ToLbKa0X80U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EmtWT4yXMYnU4QS9h4ywCg#v=onepage&q=b-24%20liberator%20electrical%20system&f=true) or
[b17 electrical system](https://www.scribd.com/document/50649178/Pilots-Manual-for-Boeing-B-17-Flying-Fortress)

Answer (score 1):

A [transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer#Effect_of_frequency) that converts the same power on a higher frequency is much smaller and lighter.

A modern design of the compact isolating power supply (say 220 V 50 Hz to 12 V DC) would often include a frequency converter, then a high frequency transformer, then a rectifier (a big 50 Hz transformer is now uncommon). But maybe the standard has settled before this complex electronics became available, or maybe because higher frequencies may be source of interference.